Nautilus on Ubuntu 24.04 runs scripts on double click, I want to change behavior to open with gted
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04, I can no longer open a shell script by double-clicking. Nautilus thinks I want to run the script. How do I set it to open the script with gted? Before upgrading, I'd go to Nautilus Preferences and change behavior, but there seems to be no behavior section in the preferences window.

What happens when you run xdg-open filename?

** (process:168410): WARNING **: 13:07:53.553: Unable to find device for URI: Containing mount for file /home/.../filename.sh not found

No, you go to the folder that has the file in the terminal and replace filename with the name of the file you're trying to open.

Yes of course, the file was in path. But your comment made me try to associate .sh files with "Text Editor", so no I can open it. Thank you. It is just that I was used to setting this in Nautilus > Behavior

The problem was solved by: right click on the file > open with > change from "Run Program" to "Text Editor".
